# How to get ID User from Laravel Controller

Tags: laravel, controller

I have 3 tables that are related as below:

topics->divisions->users that have field:

```
topics
+ id
+ name
+ division_id

divisions
+ id
+ name

users
+ id
+ name
+ email
+ division_id
+ password
```

How to get **users id** if I only know the topic id in Laravel Controller?

Comment: So you want to get all the user id's for the topic division?

Comment: yes, only id from related division in topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you created already models for your tables, so in my case **$topics** is the model for your topic table and **$user** is the model for the users table:

```
$mytopic = $topics->find(2); //2 is the id, you can use what id you need
```

Now I will get the **division_id** from the current topic:

```
$division_id = $mytopic->division_id;
```

Now we can use **$division_id** to get all the users that have this division_id:

```
$usersWithDivisionId = $users->where('division_id', $division_id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

As the following:

//topic model

```
  public function division(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\DivisionModel','division_id');
  }
```

//division model

```
   public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserModel','division_id');
  }
```

then you can get user through relation

```
 TopicModel::find(1)->division->users;
```

Comment: It shows me error : Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$division

Comment: Can make screenshot

Comment: it working, previously i use ::where('id',$request->input('id')
but, how to get id user only in variable e.g. $users = collection id in array

Comment: as this  TopicModel::find(1)->division->users()->pluck('id')